# Biml - Retain null values option in FlatFilesource

Tags: ssis, null, biml

In Biml, how to specify option in FlatFileSource to "Retain Null Values from source as well as null values in datasource"?

Answer (score 0):

Add "RetainNulls=True" as an attribute to FlatFileSource tag.